# Accessing values from dynamic number of selectInput

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

This question is related to a previous question asked by me - 
[dynamic number of selectInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700437/dynamic-number-of-selectinput)

After generating the dynamic number of selectInput options, how do I access the values? The related code from the previous question is -

```
  library(shiny)
  ui = fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "number", label = "number of selectInput",value = 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "putselect")
    )
  )
)
server = function(input,output){

  output$putselect = renderUI(
    if(input$number != 0 ){
      lapply(1:(input$number), function(i){
        selectInput(inputId = "i", label = paste0("input ",i), choices = c(2,(3)))
      })
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Suppose, I want to sum all "input$i", how do I do that? I am unable to access "input$i".

Comment: The [dynamic shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) article at RStudio suggests one method as `inputId=paste0("txt",...)` where `...` is some method for counting your variable number of inputs. From there, I wonder if you can use something like `sum(sapply(paste0("txt",1:n),`[[`,input))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one possible solution. Please note that, to prevent errors, I changed your condition from `input$number != 0` to `input$number >= 1` as well.

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "number", label = "number of selectInput",value = 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      column(
        width = 6,
        uiOutput(outputId = "putselect")
      ),
      column(
        width = 6,
        verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "text")
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input,output){
  output$putselect = renderUI(
    if(input$number >= 1){
      lapply(1:input$number, function(i){
        selectInput(inputId = paste0("input", i), label = paste("input", i), choices = c(2,(3)))
      })
    }
  )
  output$text <- renderText({
    if(input$number >= 1) {
      sum <- 0
      for(i in 1:input$number) {
        sum <- sum + as.numeric(input[[paste0("input", i)]])
      }
      return(sum)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Comment: Thankyou, It works. I have a couple of followup questions.
1) I was trying to access inputId with input$inputId instead of input[[inpuId]] like you did. Can we consistently use input[[inpuId]] in shiny?
2) When is it safe to use for loops in shiny? I have had some problems with it, for example, in creating the dynamic UI output.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem and ask your follow up questions in separate posts using the `shiny` tag. I will take a look at them along with other users.